# setBackButtonBackgroundImage without title IOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, user-interface, uiappearance

I'm trying to get a back button without a title but I can't make it work. I am really new in objective-c...

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

With that code I have my back button but also the title of the previous page.

I found some working examples using the class UIViewController but in my case the code is in the appDelegate.m file.

Any idea how I can make it work ?

Comment: To be clear, are you just trying to make a custom button that looks like the back button with no title in it?

Answer (score 9):

A very easy hack that I adapted **which uses the iOS 5 appearance proxy** is the following (needless to say, the benefit of the proxy is global change to all nav bars):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-400.f, 0)
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This method is available in iOS 5 SDK, so no worries there.

---

**EDIT**

In order to avoid the image stretching, use the following:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
return [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, image.size.width, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: It still stretches the button image.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. You forgot to mention that we need to put this in the app delegate.

Comment: @qiksand technically speaking, you have to add this code before any for your NavBars are displayed, but yeah, the appDelegate is where I tend to put it

Comment: Hacking with `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment` in this issue is not a good workaround, I think. Because you never know when the screen size will become larger than 400 points(or any value you set in the *x* position of *UIOffsetMake*). For example, **iPhone6** and **iPhone6+** breaks this hack: you will get the 'back' text on the previous page in a moment after you tap the back button.

Comment: @RalphZhouYuan if 400 is the sticky point, make it 4000. It is labeled as a hack, not a workaround, and there is no such thing as a good hack in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, you're setting the appearance proxy correctly. The issue here is setting a new title for your back button.

To do so, create a custom button with your behaviour, and use that as your new back button. **Set this before you push or pop said view controller, such as in init**

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:nil
                                                              action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
```

Comment: @user1736571 If my answer was suitable for your needs, can you please accept? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Above code use for set bacground image in Back button.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the button should have no title.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand, you are asking how to change the back button's title.

here is how i always do it

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"My Title";
```

i guess you can set it as an empty by not giving any title

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"";
```

make sure to call this function before you push the new view.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried it, but i think it should work....Put this into you viewdidLoad, i hope its what you are looking for.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
[backBarButtonItem release];
```

Answer (score -4):

Just add this line after the code you have already written :

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitle:@""];
```

Hope it works.